# Как правильно задать функцию используя JSON file

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver

Пишу парсер. Не могу правильно составить логику функции. Надо чтобы функция считывала определенные значения ключей(конкретно url_post) из json файла и по ним запускался вебдрайвер.

```
{
    "id": 1234562312,
    "title": "title",
    "id_user": 234562312,
    "pr_url": "https://...",
    "url_post": "https://...."
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1)Я пытаюсь вытащить значение "url_post" из json файла.
2)Мне нужно перейти по ссылке "url_post" с помощью веб драйвера

Comment: json_file = file.json()
url_post = json_file.get('url_post')

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_url_post():
with open("result_2.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for user_url in data:
        user_urls = user_url.get("url_post")
        users_urls.append(user_urls)
```

после создал список `users_urls =[]` ,

```
for x in users_urls:
    driver.get(url=x)
```

И таким образом драйвер по очереди запускал ссылки из списка